# Utility Classes in MVC - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

So I was wondering today, where would you put utility classes in an ASP.NET MVC app? By utility classes I mean classes that can be static and are just used to perform a function. Like a class to send an email that takes email address , subject, and body as arguments.
I would assume maybe creating a separate folder and namespace would be good enough, but wanted to get everyone opinions

Comment: Why would create utility classes in any type of project? Why is MVC singled out in your question?

Comment: Well I was wondering about MVC because it in a way forces structure. And as far as utility, I was under the impression everyone used them :) If I have an email sender code, and I split it into it's separate class to work with various parts of the system, isn't that a utility class or am I confused? I thought utility classes were once reusable in any program that aren't tied into the code

Comment: I would personally consider email sending a service, abstracted by say the interface IUserNotificationSender or so.. with proper error handling, smtp config etc that doesn't really fit in a utility function...

Comment: @Max so what would be considered a utility function? I'm trying to understand, as it seems to me I'm very confused

Comment: Well, a proper utility function in my mind is a very small function with a very defined scope and no external dependencies... Such as a function to remove whitespace, or trim a string, or get the nth element of a collection...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't. And your own example is a perfect one to show why not.

You want to send emails, right? So you create somewhere a static class `CommunicationUtilities` with a static `SendEmail()` in it. You use this method from some class which does a bunch of stuff, , for example resets the password of a user and sends him a new one by email. Perfect.

Now, what happens if you want to unit-test your class? You can't, because every time you want to test the method which resets the password, it changes the database (which is not suitable for a unit test), and moreover sends an email (which is even worse).

You may have read about Inversion of Control, which has a benefit of making unit testing easier. Articles about IoC will explain you that instead of doing something like:

```cs
void ResetPassword(UserIdentifier userId)
{
    ...
    new MailSender().SendPasswordReset(userMail, newPassword);
}
```

you do:

```cs
void ResetPassword(IMailSender sender, UserIdentifier userId)
{
    ...
    sender.SendPasswordReset(userMail, newPassword);
}
```

which allows to use mocks and stubs.

Try to apply IoC to your `CommunicationUtilities`. Right, you can't. That's why it's broken.

Comment: Hi MainMa, so if I understand correctly it's proper to still make a say background class with all the piping, and then abstract it with an interface, and pass the interface to the function instead of straight calling from the class as in your first snippet.

Comment: @user60812: in short, read about IoC. It would be difficult to explain the whole subject in a simple comment.

Comment: What about a truly generic utility function, like a string truncator?

Comment: @jbyrd: what's wrong with `"Hello, World!".Truncate(5)` returning `"Hello"`?

Comment: @MainMa - sorry, I don't follow. That's along the lines of what I want, yes. But Truncate() isn't built into c#, so I was wondering if it would make sense to stick that kind of generic utility function in some sort of utilities class.

Comment: @jbyrd: my point is that truncate is *not* an utility function: it absolutely belongs to the instance of a string. Its lack of presence in .NET Framework is by the way irrelevant; by the way, you can [easily add it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2776689/240613) as an extension method.

Comment: @MainMa - ah, I see - makes sense! I actually ended up doing just that.

Comment: This answer defines away the problem by noting that in this particular case no util class is necessary. But in general there are always some "helper" style methods that don't fit anywhere.

Comment: @usr: not necessarily. The cases where well-designed (in OOP sense) code needs utility classes are extremely rare. Although there are situations where utility classes may be a good solution, most usage of them is plainly wrong. Also see: [Are utility classes evil?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3340032/240613)

Answer (score 12):

The question is a valid one, even if the example given is not. The answer given by Maina is perfect, in a very specific context, which is not to me, the proper context for said *"utility"* classes.

Personally, I create a folder `Helpers` in which I put simple functions to be called from about anywhere, like extensions, in which case, yes, they are static.

Now, if there is a better way, I will be glad to learn, but so far:

- I see nothing wrong with Extensions.
- I see nothing wrong with grouping them in a specific Folder.

Now, an extension is just syntaxic sugar, it could as well be a classic function.

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers previously given address the actual question.  user60812 simply asked where one would place a utility class inside of an MVC project.  Everyone harked on the singular example and ranted about everything except the question at hand.

@user60812, depending on the level of abstraction you want, I would:

- A) Create a folder and create the utility class within that folder
- B) Create a project to hold the utility classes (assuming the desire for assembly reuse).
- C) Extrapolate your utilities into a service architecture and call out to them

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515973/where-can-i-put-custom-classes-in-asp-net-mvc) to a similar question with better answers.

IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Don't create static classes for utilities. Statics are bad in most cases. Don't call them managers either. Whatever it is you are working on, it should be placed in a logical namespace.

For example:

```
namespace Application.Notifications.Email
{
   public interface ISendEmailCommand
   {
      void Execute(Email email);
   }
}
```

Email address, subject and body is a separate concern, therefore I would have a class structure for that, hence why I've used `Email email` in example above.

Comment: Please explain why Static classes are  bad to hold utility methods?  I am genuinely curious as to your reasoning.